# Express the solutions of $ \arccos(z) =i$ in algebraic form $z=x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is to find all the solutions for $\arccos (z) = i$

I'm not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Are you certain that the question means $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$ rather than the inverse function $\arccos(z)$?

Comment: Actually you are right, it means arccon(z) .

Comment: Are you looking for a multivalued solution?  Maybe you wanted $z=\arccos i $ or $i=\cos z$?

Answer (score 2):

Since the question asks "Express the solutions ...", implying that there is more than one solution, perhaps what was meant was to find the solutions of $$i=\cos z.$$

$$i=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}$$ so that $$e^{2iz} -2ie^{iz}+1=0.$$ This is a quadratic equation in $e^{iz}.$  The solutions are $e^{iz}=(1\pm\sqrt{2}) i.$

Towards obtaining all solutions, we observe that for any integer $k$, $$i=\exp\left[i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)\right]$$

Dividing both sides by our expression for $i$,

$$\exp \left[{i\left(z-2k\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right] = 1\pm\sqrt{2}$$  so that

$$ z = (2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi -i \log (1\pm \sqrt{2}), \quad k\in \textrm{Integers}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\arccos z = i \Longrightarrow z= \cos i = \frac{e^{i^2} + e^{-i^2}}{2} = \frac{e^{-1}+e^{1}}{2} = \cosh 1.$$

Comment: $z=x+iy, \quad x=\cosh 1 \approx 1.54308, \quad y =0.$